# What are these JS elements?

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is from the Meteor docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#template_events.

This is a sample:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  foo: function () {
    return Session.get("foo");
  }
});
```

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and I don't quite understand what `foo` is (looks like an object). And why does it need `function`?

Why didn't they just write:

```
foo: return Session.get("foo");
```

Comment: See if this helps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

Comment: `foo: Session.get("foo")` is *not* reactive (i.e. changing the value in the session will not update foo). `foo: function() { return Session.get("foo"); }` *is* reactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code creates an anonymous object:   {foo: function ...}

The object has one property only: "foo".

The type of the property "foo" is "function", and the body of the function is 'return Session.get("foo");'

The anonymous object is passed as parameter to the method "Template.myTemplate.helpers"

---

```
foo: return Session.get("foo");
```

is not a valid javascript code